# Fullcalendar-vue3 and vanilla JS generate exceptions

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, vuejs3, cdn

I wish to use both fullcalendar and vue3, but I don't achieve it, and it seems there is problem at the initialization at the libraries themselves as I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'is')
    at j$2 (main.js:61:6988)
    at I$1 (main.js:61:6369)
    at m (main.js:61:2205)
    at I$1 (main.js:61:6186)
    at Proxy.N (main.js:61:8331)
    at mn (vue.global.min.js:1:18544)
    at _e.fn (vue.global.min.js:1:55566)
    at _e.run (vue.global.min.js:1:5996)
    at a (vue.global.min.js:1:55975)
    at I (vue.global.min.js:1:54056)

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at slice (<anonymous>)
    at j$2 (main.js:61:7077)
    at I$1 (main.js:61:6369)
    at m (main.js:61:2205)
    at I$1 (main.js:61:6186)
    at Proxy.N (main.js:61:8331)
    at mn (vue.global.min.js:1:18544)
    at _e.fn (vue.global.min.js:1:55566)
    at _e.run (vue.global.min.js:1:5996)
    at xi (vue.global.min.js:1:75573)
```

The complete code is available at the end of the message, but I present here the "'interesting parts":

- I use only regular JS (no webpack, npm, and so on), then I use the CDNs:

  ```html
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/3.2.12/vue.global.min.js" integrity="sha512-CLrLddI89KM+4mefYP8PbruyeARQAoQVwajhryM9hwM5bAeEFdtBwk0Wy6A9HlVeXyszFtXqOzg1Qy/A+Fwglg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.11.0/main.min.css" integrity="sha256-5veQuRbWaECuYxwap/IOE/DAwNxgm4ikX7nrgsqYp88=" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.11.0/main.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.11.0/locales-all.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fullcalendar/vue3@5.11.1/dist/main.global.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  ```
- as I don't use webpack (etc), I start the project this way:

  ```js
  const QApp = {
    el: '#q-app',
    data: function() {
      return {
        calendarOptions: {},
        currentEvents: []
      }
    },
    methods: {}
  }
  window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
      const app = Vue.createApp(QApp)
      app.component('FullCalendar', FullCalendar)
      app.mount('#q-app')
  });
  ```
- and finally, here is the html:

  ```html
  <div id="q-app">
      <template>
          <full-calendar
          class='demo-app-calendar'
          :options='calendarOptions'
          >
              <template v-slot:eventContent='arg'>
                  <b>{{ arg.timeText }}</b>
                  <i>{{ arg.event.title }}</i>
              </template>
          </full-calendar>
      </template>
  </div>
  ```

I have already big projects using CDNs that mix several libraries, so at first I thought to simply use the regular [fullcalendar](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar), but when I tried to customize the **eventContent** handler, the returned html that included some vue components aren't detected by **Vue**. That is the reason why I turned to **fullcalendar-vue**.

Has someone an idea of how I should do use this project ? Or perhaps how I can make Vue to detect the Components that are in the return of the **eventContent** handler with the regular [fullcalendar](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar) ?

Here is the full test code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>HTML5 : Hello World Example</title>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/3.2.12/vue.global.min.js" integrity="sha512-CLrLddI89KM+4mefYP8PbruyeARQAoQVwajhryM9hwM5bAeEFdtBwk0Wy6A9HlVeXyszFtXqOzg1Qy/A+Fwglg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.11.0/main.min.css" integrity="sha256-5veQuRbWaECuYxwap/IOE/DAwNxgm4ikX7nrgsqYp88=" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.11.0/main.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.11.0/locales-all.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fullcalendar/vue3@5.11.1/dist/main.global.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="q-app">
            <template>
                <full-calendar
                class='demo-app-calendar'
                :options='calendarOptions'
                >
                    <template v-slot:eventContent='arg'>
                        <b>{{ arg.timeText }}</b>
                        <i>{{ arg.event.title }}</i>
                    </template>
                </full-calendar>
            </template>
        </div>
<script>

let todayStr = new Date().toISOString().replace(/T.*$/, '') // YYYY-MM-DD of today

var bar = null
const QApp = {
  el: '#q-app',
  data: function() {
    return {
      calendarOptions: {
        headerToolbar: {
          left: 'prev,next today',
          center: 'title',
          right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
        },
        initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
        initialEvents: [
            {id: '54545454',title: 'All-day event',start: todayStr},
            {id: '98989898',title: 'Timed event',start: todayStr + 'T12:00:00'}
        ],
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {}
}
window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
    const app = Vue.createApp(QApp)
    app.component('FullCalendar', FullCalendar)
    app.mount('#q-app')
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the full error messages:

```
vue.global.min.js:1 You are running a development build of Vue.
Make sure to use the production build (*.prod.js) when deploying for production.
vue.global.min.js:1 [Vue warn]: Property "__b" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance. 
  at <FullCalendar class="demo-app-calendar" options= Object > 
  at <App>
_i @ vue.global.min.js:1
vue.global.min.js:1 [Vue warn]: Property "type" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance. 
  at <FullCalendar class="demo-app-calendar" options= Object > 
  at <App>
_i @ vue.global.min.js:1
vue.global.min.js:1 [Vue warn]: Property "constructor" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance. 
  at <FullCalendar class="demo-app-calendar" options= Object > 
  at <App>
_i @ vue.global.min.js:1
vue.global.min.js:1 [Vue warn]: Property "type" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance. 
  at <FullCalendar class="demo-app-calendar" options= Object > 
  at <App>
_i @ vue.global.min.js:1
vue.global.min.js:1 [Vue warn]: Property "props" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance. 
  at <FullCalendar class="demo-app-calendar" options= Object > 
  at <App>
_i @ vue.global.min.js:1
vue.global.min.js:1 [Vue warn]: Property "type" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance. 
  at <FullCalendar class="demo-app-calendar" options= Object > 
  at <App>
_i @ vue.global.min.js:1
vue.global.min.js:1 [Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of render function 
  at <FullCalendar class="demo-app-calendar" options= Object > 
  at <App>
_i @ vue.global.min.js:1
vue.global.min.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'is')
    at j$2 (main.js:61:6988)
    at I$1 (main.js:61:6369)
    at m (main.js:61:2205)
    at I$1 (main.js:61:6186)
    at Proxy.N (main.js:61:8331)
    at mn (vue.global.min.js:1:18544)
    at _e.fn (vue.global.min.js:1:55566)
    at _e.run (vue.global.min.js:1:5996)
    at a (vue.global.min.js:1:55975)
    at I (vue.global.min.js:1:54056)
vue.global.min.js:1 [Vue warn]: Property "type" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance. 
  at <FullCalendar class="demo-app-calendar" options= Object > 
  at <App>
_i @ vue.global.min.js:1
vue.global.min.js:1 [Vue warn]: Property "props" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance. 
  at <FullCalendar class="demo-app-calendar" options= Object > 
  at <App>
_i @ vue.global.min.js:1
vue.global.min.js:1 [Vue warn]: Property "key" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance. 
  at <FullCalendar class="demo-app-calendar" options= Object > 
  at <App>
_i @ vue.global.min.js:1
vue.global.min.js:1 [Vue warn]: Property "key" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance. 
  at <FullCalendar class="demo-app-calendar" options= Object > 
  at <App>
_i @ vue.global.min.js:1
vue.global.min.js:1 [Vue warn]: Property "type" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance. 
  at <FullCalendar class="demo-app-calendar" options= Object > 
  at <App>
_i @ vue.global.min.js:1
vue.global.min.js:1 [Vue warn]: Property "props" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance. 
  at <FullCalendar class="demo-app-calendar" options= Object > 
  at <App>
_i @ vue.global.min.js:1
vue.global.min.js:1 [Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of render function 
  at <FullCalendar class="demo-app-calendar" options= Object > 
  at <App>
_i @ vue.global.min.js:1
vue.global.min.js:1 [Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of scheduler flush. This is likely a Vue internals bug. Please open an issue at https://new-issue.vuejs.org/?repo=vuejs/vue-next 
  at <FullCalendar class="demo-app-calendar" options= Object > 
  at <App>
_i @ vue.global.min.js:1
main.js:61 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at slice (<anonymous>)
    at j$2 (main.js:61:7077)
    at I$1 (main.js:61:6369)
    at m (main.js:61:2205)
    at I$1 (main.js:61:6186)
    at Proxy.N (main.js:61:8331)
    at mn (vue.global.min.js:1:18544)
    at _e.fn (vue.global.min.js:1:55566)
    at _e.run (vue.global.min.js:1:5996)
    at xi (vue.global.min.js:1:75573)
```

Comment: I take it you've read the [fullcalendar vue](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/vue) docs?

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes I did; the snipped code was built after the example code before it was downsized for the post.
The documentation doesn't talk about vanilla JS, and the examples provided are about TypeScript or Webpack.